# Getting Error Code 22853 while connecting local system to Azure data factory using Self hosted Integration Runtime

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have installed Integration runtime in my local system and tried to connect to azure datafactory. But Getting Error code 22853 and connection getting failed.

Thanks for help in advance.

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1xcZ.png)]

Could you please help me to find out the reason and its corresponding solution.

Comment: Please try to use the connection like this \\server\share. see this document for details:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-file-system?tabs=data-factory

Comment: Did you give correct username and password?

Comment: I have used that specified format mentioned in the doc and my userid and password is also correct. But still it is giving Error.

Answer (score 0):

> The latest SHIR has a security fix that has been changed and does not allow access to local files by default.

To resolve the issue, you must run `.\dmgcmd.exe -DisableLocalFolderPathValidation` to disable the setting for more details, refer to [Set up an existing self-hosted IR via local PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory#set-up-an-existing-self-hosted-ir-via-local-powershell)

[image]

[image]

> **Default:** Enable security validation to disable access to file system of the local machine.

[image]

> After Disabling access to file system of the local machine using: `.\dmgcmd.exe -DisableLocalFolderPathValidation` able to access the data from linked service.

[image: Resolve]

Answer (score -1):

I tried and got similar error.

[image]

The problem is because you are using the latest version of integration runtime.

**To resolve this there are three ways:**

1. Downgrade to version **IntegrationRuntime_5.21.8277.2.msi**.
2. Instead of using a locally mapped name, they also advised using a completely qualified name in the connected service that directs users to the drive address (host). To put it another way: use **\servername\C$\folder** instead of **C:\folder**. You will get server name by typing **`hostname`** in command prompt of your pc as shown in below:
   [image]
3. check your username and password is correct.

***Connection successful:***

[image]